# Problem adding loading animation to tab panel

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add animation after clicking tab panel in Bootstrap.
When adding the loading animation to the tab panel, it works fine only in the first tab panel. In the latter, dual ring appears, but the opacity does not fully work. Where am I going wrong in the javascript code?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1ae43x6o/)

```
const tabPane = document.querySelector(".tab-pane");
const dualRing = document.querySelector(".lds-dual-ring");
const tabs = [...document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tab"]')];

for (let tab of tabs) {
  tab &&
    tab.addEventListener("click", () => {
      tabPane.classList.add("loading");
      dualRing.classList.add("loading");
      setTimeout(() => {
        tabPane.classList.remove("loading");
        dualRing.classList.remove("loading");
      }, 500);
    });
}
```

Comment: You should get the right tabPane that you need, here in your code tabPane is always the first one

Comment: You _selected_ only your first tab pane, and are only adding the `loading` class to that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the corrected fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/lk77/76fqr4ke/1/

```js
const dualRing = document.querySelector(".lds-dual-ring");
const tabs = [...document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tab"]')];

for (let tab of tabs) {
  tab &&
    tab.addEventListener("click", () => {
      let tabPane = document.querySelector(".tab-pane.active");
      tabPane.classList.add("loading");
      dualRing.classList.add("loading");
      setTimeout(() => {
        tabPane.classList.remove("loading");
        dualRing.classList.remove("loading");
      }, 500);
    });
}
```

you need to recover the active tab pane